# Logical Error Game program

Tags: java, loops, logic, user-input

The program, which is part of a board game, I am trying to create is a one that:

1- ask user to enter the Enemy base health value ( promptBaseHp ()).

2- The program generates a multiplier (2 or 3), then multiplies it by the base health value.

3- Enemy base health value must be 5,7,9,11,13 ( the array field indicates these values), and that is where I am having trouble, I need CHECK THE USER INPUT against permissible values (5,7,9,11,13).

There is something wrong that I cannot figure out, When i Run the program,it prompts the user twice, even if correct value(5,7,9,11,13) was entered. 
Can someone help me to get the function of this program right ( enter a value, check if the value 5,7,9,11,13 , then multiply it by 2 or 3)?

```
package game1;
 import java.util.Scanner;
  import java.util.Random;

   public class Enemy {
   private String [] armorTyper = {      "Fire","Water","Nature","Steel","Scales","Flesh","Dark"};
private  int [] hpValues = { 5, 7, 9, 11 ,13 };
private int enemyHP = 0 ;

Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
Random random = new Random();

  public int getFinalHp (){
   return enemyHP;
 }


public int getMultiplier (){
int multiplier = random.nextInt(1) +2 ;
return multiplier;
}


public int promptBaseHp (){

    System.out.println ("Enter base hp value (5 or 7 or 9 or 11 or 13): ");
    int hpValue = scanner.nextInt();
    System.out.println(" enemy base hp entered is :"+ hpValue);
    return hpValue;
   }


public void setBaseHp (){


boolean isAcc = comparing(promptBaseHp());

do{

if(isAcc == true){ enemyHP = getMultiplier() * promptBaseHp() ;
getFinalHp ();
}
else{ System.out.println(" must be 5/7/9/11/13 ! ");
 promptBaseHp();
 isAcc = comparing(promptBaseHp());
}
}while (isAcc == false);
}

public boolean comparing( int val) {
    boolean isAcc = false;
    for (int value : hpValues){
     isAcc = (val == value); 
     if (isAcc == true){ return isAcc; }
     else { System.out.println("invalid entery !");
     isAcc = false;}
    }
    return isAcc;
    }
}





package game1;

public class Exceutor {

 public static void main ( String [] args){

    Enemy enem = new Enemy();

    enem.getMultiplier ();
    System.out.println(" enemy hp multiplier is :"+ enem.getMultiplier());

    enem.setBaseHp ();
    enem.getFinalHp ();

    System.out.println(" enemy final hp is : "+ enem.getFinalHp());



  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Strongly suggest that you please format your code so it will make more sense to you to read as well.

You are clearly calling it twice in multiple places :

```
else{ System.out.println(" must be 5/7/9/11/13 ! ");
 promptBaseHp();
 isAcc = comparing(promptBaseHp());
}
```

change this to

```
else{ System.out.println(" must be 5/7/9/11/13 ! ");
 int value = promptBaseHp();
 isAcc = comparing(value);
}
```

Also you calling it twice here

```
boolean isAcc = comparing(promptBaseHp());

do{

if(isAcc == true){ enemyHP = getMultiplier() * promptBaseHp() ;
```

change this to :

```
int valueBaseHp = promptBaseHp();
boolean isAcc = comparing(valueBaseHp);
do{
if(isAcc == true){ enemyHP = getMultiplier() * valueBaseHp ;
```